# How to make async / await in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, async-await

I would like to simulate async and await request from Javascript to Swift 4. I searched a lot on how to do it, and I thought I found the answer with `DispatchQueue`, but I don't understand how it works.

I want to do a simple stuff:

```
if let items = result.value {
    var availableBornes = [MGLPointFeature]()

    for item in items {
        guard let id = item.id else { continue }

        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(coor.x), longitude: Double(coor.y))

        // ...

        // This is an asynchronous request I want to wait
        await _ = directions.calculate(options) { (waypoints, routes, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Error calculating directions: \(error!)")
                return
            }

            // ...

            if let route = routes?.first {
                let distanceFormatter = LengthFormatter()
                let formattedDistance = distanceFormatter.string(fromMeters: route.distance)
                item.distance = formattedDistance

                // Save feature
                let feature = MGLPointFeature()

                feature.attributes = [
                    "id": id,
                    "distance": formattedDistance
                ]

                availableBornes.append(feature)

            }
        }
    }

    // This should be called after waiting for the async requests
    self.addItemsToMap(availableBornes: availableBornes)
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: There is no Javascript in your question. What exactly is the issue with the Swift code you posted? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Don't wait. Please learn to understand asynchronous data processing in Swift. In your example just put the line `self.addItemsToMap(availableBornes: availableBornes)` **into** the completion block.

Comment: No I can’t because I have to wait the for to be finished. My asynchronous query will be called items.count times.

Comment: Then use `DispatchGroup` . It provides `enter` and `leave` statements and can `notify` when the last iteration has finished. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912000/how-to-set-up-dispatchgroup-in-asynchronous-iteration

Comment: It sounds like you want a DispatchGroup.   you'll never use "promises" again once you try out normal computer code  :-O  ;)

Comment: ah as Vadian already said .. DispatchGroup

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Thanks to [vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian)'s comment, I found what I expected, and it's pretty easy. I use `DispatchGroup()`, `group.enter()`, `group.leave()` and `group.notify(queue: .main){}`.

```
func myFunction() {
    let array = [Object]()
    let group = DispatchGroup() // initialize

    array.forEach { obj in

        // Here is an example of an asynchronous request which use a callback
        group.enter() // wait
        LogoRequest.init().downloadImage(url: obj.url) { (data) in
            if (data) {
                group.leave() // continue the loop
            }
        }
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        // do something here when loop finished
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also a non-answer, because the function will return before the code in group.notify runs

Answer (score 9):

## We have to await!

[image]

The `async-await` **Swift Evolution proposal** [**SE-0296 async/await**](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0296-async-await.md) was accepted after 2 pitches and revision modifications recently on **December 24th 2020**. This means that we will be able to use the feature in **Swift 5.5**. The reason for the delay is due to **backwards-compatibility issues with Objective-C**, see [**SE-0297**](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0297-concurrency-objc.md) **Concurrency Interoperability with Objective-C**. There are many side-effects and dependencies of introducing such a major language feature, so we can only use the experimental toolchain for now. Because SE-0296 had 2 revisions, **SE-0297** actually got accepted before SE-0296.

### General Use

We can define an **asynchronous** function with the following syntax:

```
private func raiseHand() async -> Bool {
  sleep(3)
  return true
}
```

The idea here is to include the **`async` keyword alongside the return type** since the call site **will return (`BOOL` here) when complete** if we use the new `await` keyword.

To wait for the function to complete, we can use `await`:

```
let result = await raiseHand()
```

#### Synchronous/Asynchronous

**Defining synchronous functions as asynchronous is ONLY forward-compatible** - we cannot declare asynchronous functions as synchronous. These rules apply for **function variable semantics**, and also **for closures** when passed **as parameters or as properties** themselves.

```
var syncNonThrowing: () -> Void
var asyncNonThrowing: () async -> Void
...
asyncNonThrowing = syncNonThrowing // This is OK.
```

#### Throwing functions

The same consistency constraints are applied to **throwing functions** with `throws` in their method signature, and we can use `@autoclosures` as long as the function itself is `async`.

We can also **use `try` variants such as `try?` or `try!`** whenever we await a throwing `async` function, as standard Swift syntax.

**`rethrows`** unfortunately still **needs to go through Proposal Review** before it can be incorporated because of **radical ABI differences** between the `async` method implementation and the thinner `rethrows` ABI (Apple wants to delay the integration **until the inefficiencies get ironed out** with a separate proposal).

### Networking callbacks

This is the **classic use-case** for **`async/await`** and is also where you would need to **modify your code**:

```
// This is an asynchronous request I want to wait
await _ = directions.calculate(options) { (waypoints, routes, error) in
```

Change to **this**:

```
func calculate(options: [String: Any]) async throws -> ([Waypoint], Route) {
    let (data, response) = try await session.data(from: newURL)
    // Parse waypoints, and route from data and response.
    // If we get an error, we throw.
    return (waypoints, route)
}
....
let (waypoints, routes) = try await directions.calculate(options)
// You can now essentially move the completion handler logic out of the closure and into the same scope as `.calculate(:)`
```

The asynchronous networking methods such as `NSURLSession.dataTask` now has [asynchronous alternatives](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767353-data) for async/await. However, **rather than passing an error in the completion block, the async function will throw an error.** Thus, we have to use `try await` to enable throwing behaviour. These changes are made possible because of **SE-0297** since `NSURLSession` belongs to `Foundation` which is still **largely Objective-C**.

### Code impacts

- This feature really cleans up a codebase, goodbye **Pyramid of Doom** !
- As well as cleaning up the codebase, we improve error handling for nested networking callbacks since the error and result are separated.
- We can use **multiple `await` statements in succession** to reduce the dependency on `DispatchGroup`.  **to Threading Deadlocks** when synchronising `DispatchGroup`s across different `DispatchQueue`s.
- Less error-prone because the API is clearer to read. Not considering **all exit paths** from a completions handler, and **conditional branching** means subtle bugs can build up that are not caught at compile time.
- `async / await` is not back-deployable to devices running < iOS 13, so we have to add `if #available(iOS 13, *)` checks where supporting old devices. We still need to use GCD for older OS versions.

Answer (score 6):

(Note: [Swift 5 may support `await` as you’d expect it in ES6!](https://gist.github.com/lattner/429b9070918248274f25b714dcfc7619))

What you want to look into is Swift's concept of "closures". These were previously known as "blocks" in Objective-C, or completion handlers.

Where the similarity in JavaScript and Swift come into play, is that both allow you to pass a "callback" function to another function, and have it execute when the long-running operation is complete. For example, this in Swift:

```
func longRunningOp(searchString: String, completion: (result: String) -> Void) {
    // call the completion handler/callback function
    completion(searchOp.result)
}
longRunningOp(searchString) {(result: String) in
    // do something with result
}
```

would look like this in JavaScript:

```
var longRunningOp = function (searchString, callback) {
    // call the callback
    callback(err, result)
}
longRunningOp(searchString, function(err, result) {
    // Do something with the result
})
```

There's also a few libraries out there, notably a new one by Google that translates closures into promises: https://github.com/google/promises. These might give you a little closer parity with `await` and `async`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about using callbacks, but my code is a little bit complex because I have a for loop which contains asynchronous requests. I want to execute the code outside the for loop after asynchronous requests has been done. I don't see how I could use callbacks here because I should call it many times. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yep, then what you’re looking for is a promise. Check that link there.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this framework for Swift coroutines - https://github.com/belozierov/SwiftCoroutine

Unlike DispatchSemaphore, when you call await it doesn’t block the thread but only suspends coroutine, so you can use it in the main thread as well.

```
func awaitAPICall(_ url: URL) throws -> String? {
    let future = URLSession.shared.dataTaskFuture(for: url)
    let data = try future.await().data
    return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
}

func load(url: URL) {
    DispatchQueue.main.startCoroutine {
        let result1 = try self.awaitAPICall(url)
        let result2 = try self.awaitAPICall2(result1)
        let result3 = try self.awaitAPICall3(result2)
        print(result3)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In iOS 13 and up, you can now do this using Combine. `Future` is analogous to `async` and the `flatMap` operator on publishers (`Future` is a publisher) is like `await`. Here's an example, loosely based on your code:

```
Future<Feature, Error> { promise in
  directions.calculate(options) { (waypoints, routes, error) in
     if let error = error {
       promise(.failure(error))
     }

     promise(.success(routes))
  }
 }
 .flatMap { routes in 
   // extract feature from routes here...
   feature
 }
 .receiveOn(DispatchQueue.main) // UI updates should run on the main queue
 .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
    // completion is either a .failure or it's a .success holding
    // the extracted feature; if the process above was successful, 
    // you can now add feature to the map
 }, receiveValue: { _ in })
 .store(in: &self.cancellables)
```

**Edit**: I went into more detail in [this blog post](https://moreindirection.wordpress.com/2020/05/13/using-combine-to-simulate-async-await-in-swift/).

Comment: This doesn't allow you to "await" anything, the function that this happens in will still happen asynchronously, meaning you can't return the result from the function this code is in. That makes this a non-answer to the question

Answer (score 5):

You can use semaphores to simulate async/await.

```
func makeAPICall() -> Result <String?, NetworkError> {
            let path = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
            guard let url = URL(string: path) else {
                return .failure(.url)
            }
            var result: Result <String?, NetworkError>!
            
            let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
                if let data = data {
                    result = .success(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
                } else {
                    result = .failure(.server)
                }
                semaphore.signal()
            }.resume()
            _ = semaphore.wait(wallTimeout: .distantFuture)
            return result
 }
```

And here is example how it works with consecutive API calls:

```
func load() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
           let result = self.makeAPICall()
                .flatMap { self.anotherAPICall($0) }
                .flatMap { self.andAnotherAPICall($0) }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch result {
                case let .success(data):
                    print(data)
                case let .failure(error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the [article](https://medium.com/@michaellong/how-to-chain-api-calls-using-swift-5s-new-result-type-and-gcd-56025b51033c) describing it in details.

And you can also use promises with PromiseKit and similar libraries

Answer (score 1):

Async/await is now officially supported in Swift.

It would yield be something like this

```
func myFunction() async throws {
    let array: [Object] = getObjects()

    let images = try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Data.self, returning: [Data].self) { group in
        array.forEach { object in
            group.async {
                try await LogoRequest().downloadImage(url: object.url)
            }
        }
        return try await group.reduce([], {$0 + [$1]})
    }
    // at this point all `downloadImage` are done, and `images` is populated
    _ = images
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use async/ await below like this,

```
enum DownloadError: Error {

case statusNotOk
case decoderError

}
```

Method Call

```
override func viewDidLoad()  {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    async{
        do {
            let data =  try await fetchData()
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:.mutableLeaves)
                print(json)
            }catch{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
    }
}

func fetchData() async throws -> Data{
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json")!
    let request = URLRequest(url:url)
    let (data,response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    
    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else{
        
        throw DownloadError.statusNotOk
    }
    return data
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here you can see a basic difference, how the callBack replacing by async/await**

[image: Here you can see a basic difference, how the callBack replacing by async/await]

Basically, scene A and scene B = Call API by the closure.
Scene C and scene D= Calling API by Async/Await.
Scene E = Serial API call by nested closure.
Scene F= Serial API call by Async/Await.
Scene G = Parallel API call by Async/Await.

**Parallel API call**

[image]

Comment: This Medium article for more info:

https://medium.com/@nirajpaul.ios/async-await-actors-in-swift-e2941e5f6dbf