# Modifying array from asynchronous call not modifying the array swift

Tags: arrays, swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to modify an array of objects that I retrieve from an asynchronous call with the results from another asynchronous call.  Basically I retrieve an array of results and there is a field `messages` that is returned nil from my server call.  I then need to make another server call with the **id** of each `result` in a for loop to get the `messages` array. I then set the `messages` to the returned value.

I just learned about using **DispatchGroup()** about 20 minutes ago from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48718976/3272438, so bear with me.

The issue I get is that when I do **print("C0: (self.res)")** it prints out all of the items including the `messages` I just added.  When **print("C2: (self.res)")** prints in the `group.notify(...)`, all of the `messages` fields print out **nil**.  I'm stumped and I have tried everything I could think of. Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
By changing the following group.notify() never gets called

```
Service.getMessages(resultId: self.res![index].id, completionHandler: { (latestMessage, response, error) in

        if let latestMessage = latestMessage {
            self.res![index].messages = [latestMessage]
            print("L2: \(self.res![index].messages)")
            print("C0: \(self.res)")
        }
        group.leave() // continue the loop
    })
```

ViewController.Swift

```
var res: [ResultDTO]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let group0 = DispatchGroup()

    group0.enter()
    Service.getResults { (results, response, error) in
        guard var results = results else { print("PROBLEM"); return }
        self.res = results
        group0.leave()
    }

    group0.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("in group0")
        let group = DispatchGroup() // initialize
        for index in 0..<self.res!.count {
            group.enter() // wait
            Service.getMessages(resultId: self.res![index].id, completionHandler: { (latestMessage, response, error) in

                if let latestMessage = latestMessage {
                    self.res![index].messages = [latestMessage]
                    print("L2: \(self.res![index].messages)")
                    print("C0: \(self.res)")
                }

            })
            group.leave() // continue the loop
        }

        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            print("In group notify")

            do {
                print("C2: \(self.res)")
                for index in 0..< self.res!.count {
                    print("L4: \(self.res![index].messages)")
                }
                // ... configure my view with the data
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: As an aside: kind of ugly database architecture, right? Is it possible to fix how the data is architected instead of jumping through these hoops on the client?

Comment: Yeah I suppose it is possible. I'll have to look into redesigning the database, but for the time being I would like to understand why this seemingly decent code won't work.

Comment: What's your database setup? Serverless NoSQL?

Comment: Using an Oracle DB and java backend with Hibernate.

Comment: I don't have experience with Oracle databases so I don't know how to best exploit them. If I were you, I'd spend the time figuring out how to simplify this data grab. Can it be reduced to one network call? Why the hesitancy to denormalize this data?

Comment: I'll have to do some planning on the best way to simplify the data retrieval. It was just how we designed it instead of returning all of the data at once when it's not needed just return the required pieces of information. Code- I tried moving it and it doesn't enter `group.notify()` or print `In group notify`.

Comment: Please show the definition of `getMessages`. The behavior described is suggesting that your  `getMessages` is not coded in a good manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simplify your data handling by using one dispatch group (since one is all you need):

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    private var results: [ResultDTO]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getResults()
    }

    private func getResults() {

        Service.getResults { (results, response, error) in

            guard let results = results,
                results.count > 0 else {
                    return
            }

            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

            for r in results {

                dispatchGroup.enter()
                Service.getMessages(resultId: r.id, completionHandler: { (latestMessage, response, error) in

                    if let latestMessage = latestMessage {
                        r.messages = [latestMessage]
                    }
                    dispatchGroup.leave()

                }

            }

            dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
                self.results = results
            })

        }

    }

}
```

Consider this only a starting point. If this were production code, I'd implement error handling and background queueing (assuming the data is returned on the main thread).

Comment: Trying to implement it and I get the following error: `Incorrect argument label in call (have 'queue:execute:', expected 'queue:work:')` with `dispatchGroup.notify(...)`

Comment: You're using `notify(queue: DispatchQueue, work: DispatchWorkItem)` when you should be using `notify(queue: DispatchQueue, execute: () -> Void)`

Comment: Or just use a trailing closure like you did `dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) { ... }`

Comment: I'm not sure it's hitting the `dispatchGroup.notify(...)` because if I put a `print("hello")` nothing prints

Comment: You're not still using multiple dispatch groups are you?

Comment: No I copied and pasted your code and just have one group

Comment: What is the data type of `results` from the first network call?

Comment: A custom `resultDTO` struct with `{ id, messages, timestamp, ... }` and I just want to set the `messages` field. If I put print statements it prints everywhere except inside `dispatchGroup.notify(...)`

Comment: `results` is an array of `resultDTO` right? When you print at dispatch enter and dispatch leave, does it print an equal number of enters and leaves and does that equal the number of results returned from the first network call?

Comment: Yes it is an array of resultDTO. Initial size is 20 and on enter = 20, on leave = 6. I added my print statements to your answer. A prints out `AAA: 0
AAA: 1
AAA: 2
AAA: 3
AAA: 4
AAA: 5
AAA: 6
AAA: 7
AAA: 8
AAA: 9
AAA: 10
AAA: 11
AAA: 12
AAA: 13
AAA: 14
AAA: 15
AAA: 16
AAA: 17
AAA: 18
AAA: 19` and B prints out: `BBB: 0
BBB: 1
BBB: 6
BBB: 4
BBB: 15
BBB: 18`

Comment: No luck yet... Still not hitting the `notify`

Comment: Then it's almost certainly your data or the server. Check to make sure that all of the data actually exists. Also in the `Service.getMessages` return, `if let error = error { print(error) }` and see if the server is returning an error. The code is right and we know it works because its iterating through the loop making the proper number of network calls. It's just not getting back the same number of results, which indicates a server-side error.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that it is most likely server side and I'm looking at that now

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using Google Firestore? Btw, 20 successive calls to the database is perhaps hitting a server limitation, which is another reason to restructure your data to limit this data grab to one call. When messages are created, make two writes instead of one and then you can get all of this data in one go.

Comment: We just decided on a custom backend implementation rather than Google Firebase or Firestore. It's just how things worked out.  Yeah definitely need to restructure the data to be retrieved easier than multiple calls. BUT, on the bright side I found my problem. It happened to be in my API call. I have a method to automatically decode the data to the required object type and if the decode() failed it just didn't return. I added a completion handler() and now it enters the `notify` block but still doesn't have `messages` in the object.